# Sort by bool values of each object and show in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, sorting

I have a `UITableView`, inside that I am using `UICollectionView`. So I have multiple collection view - where user can scroll horizontally. Now in my each collection view I have some data to show. But each cell object contains the bool value. If bool is false, then I need to show that object title as first in my collection view followed by bool is true.

My JSON as follow:

```
first obj:({
     name =ruler1;
     com = "        1";
     Dele = "";
     isTrue = false
 },
 {
     name =rule2r;
     com = "        1";
     Dele = "";
     isTrue = true
 },
 {
     name =rule3r;
     com = "        1";
     Dele = "";
     isTrue = false
 })

 sec obj:({
     name =ruler name1;
     com = "        1";
     Dele = "";
     isTrue = true
 },
 {
     name =ruler name 2;
     com = "        1";
     Dele = "";
     isTrue = false
 },
 {
     name =ruler name 3;
     com = "        1";
     Dele = "";
     isTrue = false
 })
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I'm just showing the label as normal like :

```
collectionCell.cellTitleLabel.text = Info["name"] as? String ?? ""
```

But, How can I sort and show which ever object is false? That needs to be show at first.

For ex:

`ruler1 (false), rule3r(false) , rule2r(true)` like same.

Are there any helpful solution? I have tried with sort, but didn't help me much.

Update:

I have following code to show label in `collectionView` at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
if let gamesList = skillInfo?["data_list"]  as? [[String: Any]] {
    let gameInfo = gamesList[indexPath.item]
    collectionCell.cellTitleLabel.text = gameInfo["name"] as? String ?? ""
}
```

`skillInfo` is my `JSON` list that I have added in my bundle.

Comment: Using dictionaries will make this painful. Please, parse data into objects first.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by view step:

1. Set the JSON array into object model
2. Then use this function to sort the array

ex. your data array is : `arrData`

**then you use:**

```
arrData.sort { (first, second) -> Bool in

return !first. isTrue

 }
```

this sort the false value object at first place

Comment: i am not using any model class..From bundle json i am fetching all the data and i am showing

Comment: @david please use the model class

Comment: its bit existing project, cant use model inbetween and to create...any solution without model ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get shored array of dictionary by a boolean value.

```
let sortedArray = (myArray as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "isTrue", ascending: false)]) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
```

If you want to get true value first then `ascending = false` and if you want to get false value first then pass `ascending = true`

See the output sorted an array of dictionary in this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I am getting error like `String is not convertiable to string?` in my `key: "isTrue"`

Comment: you are trying to convert into a string? see my output screenshot, your array same or different?

Comment: i updated my post. please have a look. I am using json file which is in my bundle

Answer (score 0):

This to sort dictionary array.

Were, ascending = true will return data with isTrue = 0 first,

when ascending = false will return data with isTrue = 1 first.

You can achieve your needs with the following a line,Try this code and let me know if you there still any issue.

```
 func sortJSONArray() {

    let bundle = Bundle.init(for: StackOverflowViewController.self)

    guard let jsonPath = bundle.path(forResource: "StackOVerflow", ofType: "json"),
        let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: jsonPath)) else {
            return
    }

    if let jsonObjects = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization
        .ReadingOptions.allowFragments)) as? NSArray {

        let arrFiltered = jsonObjects.filter{($0 as! [String: Any])["isTrue"] as? Int == 0}
        let arrSorted = jsonObjects.sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "isTrue", ascending: true)]) as! [[String:AnyObject]]

        print(arrFiltered)
        print(arrSorted)
    }
}
```

This to filter a dictionary array, (If you want to show data which isTrue = 0 only)

```
let arrFiltered = jsonObjects.filter{($0 as! [String: Any])["status"] as? Int == 0}
```

Comment: please check my updated post. i am using json list which is in my bundle. Not as array or module.How can i sort with my updated code in my post